# EDIT: Execution order issue (Originally: How do I change primitive variable values in Java? )

Tags: java, android, variables, scope, order-of-execution

**EDIT:** As @NormR suggested, the execution order was totally different than I expected. `Value check a` was basically the last thing to be executed in `onCreate`, and that was the root of my whole issue.

Unless it's poor practice, I plan on fixing behavior by moving my place prep function calls to just above `Value check a`. It seems to be working well so far.


I'm making an Android app that accesses Google Places with an API request. I was finally ready to test with a variable based location (instead of hardcoding coordinates in the request), and I keep having issues.

I've been playing with this for a few mornings, and I can't seem to understand what is happening. I have `dblLatitude` & `dblLongitude` initialized to coordinates in the middle of nowhere, at the population center of the US. I want to change their values to whatever `location` holds for the equivalent variables.

I know `dblLatitude`/`dblLongitude` hold the values I want immediately after being assigned (at `Value check a`), but they revert back to their initialized values (by the time it reaches `Value check b`, and anytime after that). I've tried stepping through with the debugger, and I've even reverted to trying toast messages to see what's happening, but I still don't know exactly when or why the values change back to the default ones (or rather, what I'm doing wrong to not actually change their values in a meaningful way in the first place).

In my mind (with mainly C++ experience), the desired values should just simply persist until they're changed again - they're not being declared inside `onSuccess`, so I don't see any scope issues.

Another thread lead me to try setting the values with functions in place of the `dblLatitude = location.getLatitude();` lines (a `void` I would call with `setCoords(location);`, and another attempt with two `Double` returning functions I would call with `dblLatitude = getLat(location);` & `dblLongitude= location.getLongitude();`). But in both cases, I still saw the same behavior. The values I wanted were present at `Value check a`, and the values went back to(?) as they were initialized at `Value check b`.

How can I fix what I have in place to get the behavior I'm looking for?

Or should I simply shift all my place prep function calls to be inside the `if` statement in `OnSuccess`?

Thanks in advance for any insight - and please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
Double dblLatitude = 37.503957;
Double dblLongitude = -92.220984;

FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
        .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    dblLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                    dblLongitude= location.getLongitude();

                    // Value check a
                }
            }
        });
        // Value check b

        /*
            A couple function calls to prepare a list of places near the coordinates
        */

    }
    // Where I put attempted function workarounds
}
```

Comment: Is the code at Value check a executed before or after the code at Value check b? I think b is executed first showing the old values and a later with the new values. The onSuccess method is called when the event happens, long after b.

Comment: Ohhhhhh. That's exactly what's happening... That didn't even come to mind as a vague possibility, so I didn't check the execution order at all. Thank you!!